# extract string between square brackets at second occurrence

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string pattern like this:

```
She is [my] little [daughter].
```

How can I extract `daughter` from the above string?

Comment: A simple way is to extract all `[...]`'s and pick the second (or the last) one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an anchored regex with capturing group.

```
^.*?\[[^\]]*\].*?\[([^\]]*)\]
```

Then get the string you want from group index 1.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vW6jU8/1)

```
> console.log(/^.*?\[[^\]]*\].*?\[([^\]]*)\]/.exec('She is [my] little [daughter].')[1])
daughter
```

Comment: Thank you, Avinash. BTW, Can I use `^.*?\[.*\].*?\[(.*)\]` instead of your pattern?

Comment: use the non-greedy form `^.*?\[.*?\].*?\[(.*?)\]` .  https://regex101.com/r/vW6jU8/2

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
/\[[^\]]*\][^[]*\[([^\]]*)\]/
```

And grab captured group #1

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lN8dF1/1)

Comment: In JS you cannot capture subpattern matches in global search ([ref.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)).

Comment: Where did you see global search in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
var st="She is [my] little [daughter].";
console.log(st.match(/.*\[(\w+)\]/)[1]);
```