# Get the second match by regex

Tags: regex, ruby, fluentd

I want to get the second occurrence of the matching pattern (inside the brackets) by using a regex.
Here is the text

```
[2019-07-29 09:48:11,928] @hr.com [2] [AM] WARN
```

I want to extract **2** from this text.I tried using

```
(?<Ten ID>((^)*((?<=\[).+?(?=\]))))
```

But it matches **2019-07-29 09:48:11**,**928** , **2** , **AM**.
How to get only **2** ?

Comment: Try `(?<=\[)\d+(?=\])` https://regex101.com/r/HfGtlN/1

Comment: Here is a [bunch of solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57671253/3832970) with an improved @Thefourthbird's suggestion, too.

Comment: @Wiktor I am using this in fluentd to separate logs. I can only use just the regex expression. Can you  give me a solution?

Comment: Use `\[(?<val>\d+)\]`, the value you need is in Group "val".

Comment: @Wiktor this is what I needed, Can you please explain this a bit!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a substring between `[` and `]` (square brackets) excluding the brackets you may use `/\[([^\]\[]*)\]/` regex:

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `([^\]\[]*)` - Capturing group 1: any 0+ chars other than `[` and `]`
- `\]` - a `]` char.

To get the *second* match, you may use

```
str = '[2019-07-29 09:48:11,928] @hr.com [2] [AM] WARN'
p str[/\[[^\]\[]*\].*?\[([^\]\[]*)\]/m, 1]
```

See [this Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/8SvMKo). Here,

- `\[[^\]\[]*\]` - finds the first `[...]` substring
- `.*?` - matches any 0+ chars as few as possible
- `\[([^\]\[]*)\]` - finds the second `[...]` substring and captures the inner contents, returned with the help of the second argument, `1`.

To get Nth match, you may also consider using

```
str = '[2019-07-29 09:48:11,928] @hr.com [2] [AM] WARN'
result = ''
cnt = 0
str.scan(/\[([^\]\[]*)\]/) { |match| result = match[0]; cnt +=1; break if cnt >= 2}
puts result #=> 2
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/G6FZ61)

**Note** that if there are fewer matches than you expect, this solution will return the last matched substring.

Another solution that is not generic and only suits this concrete case: extract the first occurrence of an int number inside square brackets:

```
s = "[2019-07-29 09:48:11,928] @hr.com [2] [AM] WARN"
puts s[/\[(\d+)\]/, 1] # => 2
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/GFXaNF).

To use the regex in Fluentd, use

```
\[(?<val>\d+)\]
```

and the value you need is in the `val` named group. `\[` matches `[`, `(?<val>\d+)` is a *named capturing group* matching 1+ digits and `]` matches a `]`.

[Fluentular](http://fluentular.herokuapp.com) shows:

> Copy and paste to `fluent.conf` or `td-agent.conf`
>
> ```
>      
>       type tail 
>       path /var/log/foo/bar.log 
>       pos_file /var/log/td-agent/foo-bar.log.pos 
>       tag foo.bar 
>       format /\[(?\d+)\]/
> ```
>
> **Records**
>
> ```
>  Key    Value
>  val    2
> ```

Answer (score 0):

From [extract string between square brackets at second occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28780476/extract-string-between-square-brackets-at-second-occurrence)

```
/\[[^\]]*\][^[]*\[([^\]]*)\]/
```

You can use this, and need the second capture group.

Comment: Is there a way that I can get **2** as the full match. I want this to be used in fluentd, It only takes the full match!

Answer (score 0):

If you know that it's always the second match, you can use `scan` and take the second result:

```
"[2019-07-29 09:48:11,928] @hr.com [2] [AM] WARN".scan(/\[([^\]]*)\]/)[1].first
# => "2"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def nth_match(str, n)
  str[/(?:[^\[]*\[){#{n}}([^\]]*)\]/, 1]
end
```

```
str = "Little [Miss] Muffet [sat] on a [tuffet] eating [pie]."

nth_match(str, 1)  #=> "Miss" 
nth_match(str, 2)  #=> "sat" 
nth_match(str, 3)  #=> "tuffet" 
nth_match(str, 4)  #=> "pie" 
nth_match(str, 5)  #=> nil
```

We could write the regular expression in free-spacing mode to document it.

```
/
(?:       # begin a non-capture group
  [^\[]*  # match zero or more characters other than '['
  \[      # match '['
){#{n}}   # end non-capture group and execute it n times
(         # start capture group 1,
  [^\]]*  # match zero or more characters other than ']' 
)         # end capture group 1
\]        # match ']'
/x        # free-spacing regex definition mode

/(?:[^\[]*\[){#{n}}([^\]]*)\]/
```